# Windows 7 cmd batch check installed application

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

This may sound like a simple question, but I'd be grateful for a quick solution:

I have a batch script which runs at logon (with elevated privileges) that should run only if a specific program version is installed.

I'm not able to check the "Program Files" directory because it doesn't get installed there. However, I'm able to see it under installed applications. As well, its program name says Radmin Server 3.4 (including version number in title), which I'd like to check.

Does anyone has an idea of how I can ask for that specific value? I would like to ask if Radmin Server 3.4 is installed.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please tell us what you have researched and attempted to resolve this.

Comment: If the program is installed as a compliant application in Windows you should be able to use WMIC. Obviously this is specific to your environment but if I type WMIC Product where "Name like '%Office%'" get Name it shows me all that is similar, so if you was to use "Name like '%Radmin%'" you should get just the one listed with that version... You will then have to pipe this to a variable in your script. If you think this will work but need more help I can write up a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with Powershell, you can do this by using the [*GetWmiObject* cmdlet with the _Win32_Product_](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software.aspx) option.